# How do I change the GTK theme to those found on the page given in the description?

Tags: 12.10, gtk

I've downloaded some GTK themes from http://ubuntu-art.org/index.php?xcontentmode=100&PHPSESSID=180c7cef6c965351b9d18e19e3d037e9 and I can't see any instructions on how to install them. For additional information I am running Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal, have Ubuntu Tweak already installed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Home.  Was just checking out your question,  If you downloaded themes from the source in your link, this will cause you more trouble as they are GTK2 themes.  You need GTk3 w/GTK2  to work properly in 12.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess if it is supported by your desktop you can easily run nautilus with admin rights:

- gksu nautilus

then just go to usr/share/themes folder and unzip files you have downloaded from site.
Use `gnome-tweak-tool` ot `ubuntu tweak` to chose themes
or you can add webupd8theme repository by

- sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/themes && sudo apt-get update

and install themes via synaptic package manager -just search for themes. https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/themes

Comment: Thanks mate! (I'm Aussy so it doesn't sound weird)